# How to add custom operations to with NSwag

Tags: asp.net-core, openapi, nswag

I'm trying to add a route that isn't a `Controller` into my NSwag generated Open API document. I tried implementing `IDocumentProcessor` but the operations collection there is immutable.

How can I add an additional, non-`Controller` operation to the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DocumentProcessorContext`'s `Document` property (a `OpenApiDocument`), there is a `Paths` collection where one could add the required resources/operations at that point.